# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() running php through shell

Tags: php, oracle, php-ini

I have a redhat server with httpd and oci8 installed properly. I can access correctly oracle functions like oci_connect() when using a script runs through the browser. This is my problem:
I have a shell script shell.sh that has the content:

```
shell.sh:
/php/bin/path script.php
```

and in script.php I have the code:

```
script.php
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pass', 'MYDB');
```

I am having the error **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect().**
I tried to log phpinfo() inside the script.php and I see that **oci8 is not loaded**! How can I load it?

This is what I tried:

```
shell.sh

/php/bin/path -c "/path/to/php.ini" script.php
```

and inside php.ini
I added :

```
php.ini
extension=oci8.so
```

When running only script.php throught the browser for exemple everything connect correctly and phpinfo has all extensions activated.

Anyone encountered this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

---

What does the following command show you?

```
php --ini | grep Loaded
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
```

in my case there is an extra php.ini for the CLI

Comment: I get /etc/opt/php-7.4/php.ini using php_ini_loaded_file() function in script.php. That path is the same used when running the script through browser. I just found out that the oracle instant client was installed without using "--with-oci8=shared" option so I am wondering if that is why php is not loading it directly. However since the same php.ini is used I expect it to find my so file..strange

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the php.ini file and oracle instant client library files did not have the good permissions. Once I added the correct permission, everything worked